# Can we pass browser stack capabilities in run time?

Tags: javascript, protractor, cross-browser, browserstack

Is it possible to pass browser stack capabilities during run time? The below list of capabilities has been passed in config file. Every time when I run my script I will comment rest of the browsers and run using protractor cucumber.Browserstackconfig.js . Is it possible to run only particular device or browser without commenting the other capabilities. I have also tried multicapabilities where the scripts run across all device mentioned. Could some one provide a solution for this?

```
'os_version' : '5.0',
'device' : 'Samsung Galaxy S6',
'real_mobile' : 'true',
'browserstack.local' : 'false',
'resolution':'800x600',
'acceptSslCerts': true
'deviceOrientation' :'landscape'


 'os_version' : '11.2',
 'device' : 'iPhone 6',
 'real_mobile' : 'true',
 'browserstack.local' : 'false',
 'browserName': 'Chrome',
 'browser_version': '68.0',
 'acceptSslCerts': true,
 'resolution':'800x600',

 'os_version' : '9.1',
 'device' : 'iPad Mini 4',
 'browserstack.local' : 'false',
 'acceptSslCerts': true

 'os': 'Windows',
 'os_version': '10',
 'browserName': 'IE',
 'browser_version': '11.0',
 'resolution': '1024x768',
 'acceptSslCerts': true,
```

Comment: Please, could you describe your final goal? And why you failed wit `multiCapabilities`?

Comment: For parallel execution multi capabilities work fine. But we don't want our scripts to run every time in all browsers. Instead we like to run in IE or Safari based on the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

1) Prepare a file `capabilities.js` to hold your all browser capabilities and export a `get()` function as following:

```
var capabilitiesList = {
    'S6': {
        'os_version': '5.0',
        'device': 'Samsung Galaxy S6',
        'real_mobile': 'true',
        'browserstack.local': 'false',
        'resolution': '800x600',
        'acceptSslCerts': true,
        'deviceOrientation': 'landscape'
    },

    'iPhone6': {
        'os_version': '11.2',
        'device': 'iPhone 6',
        'real_mobile': 'true',
        'browserstack.local': 'false',
        'browserName': 'Chrome',
        'browser_version': '68.0',
        'acceptSslCerts': true,
        'resolution': '800x600',
    },

    'iPad4': {
        'os_version': '9.1',
        'device': 'iPad Mini 4',
        'browserstack.local': 'false',
        'acceptSslCerts': true
    },

    'ie': {
        'os': 'Windows',
        'os_version': '10',
        'browserName': 'IE',
        'browser_version': '11.0',
        'resolution': '1024x768',
        'acceptSslCerts': true,
    }
};

module.exports = function get(browsers) {

    if (!!browsers) {

        let multiCapabilities = [];

        browsers = browsers.split('=')[1].trim();

        browsers.split(',').forEach(function (browser) {
            browser = browser.trim();
            if (capabilitiesList.keys().includes(browser)) {
                multiCapabilities.push(capabilitiesList[browser]);
            }
        });

        return multiCapabilities.length === 0 ? undefined : multiCapabilities;
    }
};
```

2) Change protractor `conf.js` to accept browsers from cmd line, then call the `get()` function to return an capabilities list.

```
let capabilities = require('./capabilities.js');

let browsers = process.argv.find((it) => {
    return it.includes('--browsers=');
});

exports.config = {

    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['./test.js'],

    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    },

    multiCapabilities: capabilities.get(browsers),

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        // If true, print colors to the terminal.
        showColors: true,
        // Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 3600000,
        // Function called to print jasmine results.
        print: function() {},
    }
};
```

3) Specify browser in cmd line

```
protractor conf.js --browsers=ie  // for running only one browser
protractor conf.js --browsers=ie,iPad4  // for running multiple browsers
protractor conf.js  // will run on chrome browser
```

Comment: Where do we call the browsers from?

Comment: See the `3)` in my answer.